# Prove that the given sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

prove that the sequence $\frac{2n^2 + n + 10}{n^2 + 5}$ is convergent

I've come down as far as $\left|\frac{n}{n^2 + 5}\right| < \epsilon$,

however i don't know what the next step is.

Comment: $n/(n^2+5)<n/(n^2)=1/n$ which is simpler to bound less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there! So basically the + 5 doesnt have any significance as you take n to infinity, and so you can simplify to 1/n. Right?

Comment: Amit: In these one needs to make sure the bound goes the right way. Here the fact that $n/(n^2+5)<n/(n^2)$ is in the right direction, since then any upper bound on $n/n^2=1/n$ is also a bound on $n/(n^2+5).$ If it were $n/(n^2-5)$ for example one would have to adjust to saying that was at most something like $2/n$ for $n$ beyond some point.